# How to find first order density of the sample function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm asked to find the first order density of the following process:

$x(t)=A\cos(2\pi ft + \theta)$

where, $\theta$ is uniformly distributed over -$\pi$ and $\pi$ and f is a constant.

I'm not sure how to find the first order density function of the whole process. I can find the density function of the individual components. The density function of $\theta$ is given by:

$f(\theta)= 1/2 \pi$, if $-\pi <\theta <\pi$

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X(t)$ is a time-varying stochastic process here. So, for fixed $t$, $X(t)$ is a random variable and is defined as: $X(t)=A\mathbb{cos}(2\pi ft+\theta)$, where $\theta$ is Uniformly distributed over [$-\pi,\pi]$

If $\theta$ follows $U[-\pi,\pi]$, then for fixed $t$, $Y(t)=2\pi ft+\theta$ follows $U[2\pi ft-\pi,2\pi ft+\pi]$ so that, $X(t)=A\mathbb{cos}(Y(t))$ and the pdf of $X(t)$ looks like:

$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}.\frac{1}{\sqrt(A^2-x^2)}$, where $2\pi ft-\pi \le \mathbb{cos}^{-1}(\frac{x}{A}) \le 2\pi ft+\pi$

That is, $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}.\frac{1}{\sqrt(A^2-x^2)}$, where $0 \le \mathbb{cos}^{-1}(\frac{x}{A}) \le \pi$ provided $ft$ is an integer.

or, $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}.\frac{1}{\sqrt(A^2-x^2)}$, where $|x|\le A$

which is the first order density of $X(t)$ for fixed $t$

[NB: One of the methods for deriving the pdf of $X(t)$ is the transformation of variables that I used here]